# For loop within a Pandas dataframe to add a new column after each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby, geopandas

I have a dataframe that has a variety of properties on a dataset of buildings. These buildings are all assigned to a dwelling group (Apartment/ Semi detached house/ Detached house/ Terraced house) and a small area code. These buildings also have a year of construction column, however no unique identifier apart from their small area (circa 80 buildings).

I want to write a for loop that groups these buildings into their dwelling group, and then break them down into their small area and assigns them individually the median year of construction for that dwelling group in that small area. For example, divide up all apartments in small area 12345, and assign them individually (in a new column) the median year of construction for apartments in that small area.

So far geo_dwelling is a GeoDataFrame with columns;

```
In [20]: geo_dwelling.head(5)
```

Out[20]:
cso_small_area Dublin Postcode  Year of construction Year of construction range Dwelling type description Energy Rating  ... height_ag  height_bg floors_ag  floors_bg  category  Dwelling Group
7101      268109005        DUBLIN 1                2009.0               2005 onwards            Mid floor apt.            B3  ...     10.02          0         3          0         R       Apartment
7101      268109005        DUBLIN 1                2009.0               2005 onwards            Mid floor apt.            B3  ...     10.73          0         3          0         R       Apartment
7101      268109005        DUBLIN 1                2009.0               2005 onwards            Mid floor apt.            B3  ...     10.56          0         3          0         R       Apartment
7101      268109005        DUBLIN 1                2009.0               2005 onwards            Mid floor apt.            B3  ...     10.75          0         3          0         R       Apartment
7101      268109005        DUBLIN 1                2009.0               2005 onwards            Mid floor apt.            B3  ...     10.85          0         3          0         R       Apartment

```
geo_dwelling = geo_dropped[
geo_dropped["Dwelling Group"].str.contains("Apartment", na=False)]

geo_dwelling.groupby(["cso_small_area"])[["Year of construction"]].median()
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practise to create 'for' loops in a pandas dataframe (Takes a lot of time too!). I believe the answer to your question lies in this article:

[How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorry this is my first post to SO I'm sure there's a lot of bad practise in what I've just done!

Comment: @oinsdoherty3, no problem. It's normal :-) Can you please accept the answer as the right one if it was good for you?

Comment: done now! Thanks again